# Pretty woman - is it a test or a Mitzvah

Tags: army-military-war, ki-teitzei

The sources talk a lot about the procedure of "אשת יפת תואר" (like Rambam Melachim 8,2 and on).

So for the soldiers, is the Pretty Woman allowed but "bad" (*like "Patur but Ossur", see Rashi's consequences to Ben Sorer Umoreh*) or is it a Mitvzah to follow the procedure as it's only allowed for the most pious Tzaddikim?

Comment: Gemara says something about the link between Ben sorer umore and years toar. I'm almost sure or about Ben hassenua

Comment: @kouty Rashi right there quotes the Gemara. One who marries a Yefas Toar will come to hate her, and from that union the child will be a Ben Sorer u’Moreh.

Comment: @AlBerko Just to be clear on the terminology: what you’re really asking is reshus (permission) vs. chovah (obligation). Asking if it’s a mitzvah or not is misleading, as it’s clearly a mitzvah, just perhaps not ideal to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The [Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) describes it as a concession to man's inclinations that is merely better than the alternative:

[**Kiddushin 21b**](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=21b&format=pdf)

> ת"ר וראית בשביה בשעת שביה אשת ואפילו אשת איש יפת תואר לא דברה תורה אלא
>   כנגד יצר הרע מוטב שיאכלו ישראל בשר תמותות שחוטות ואל יאכלו בשר
>   תמותות נבילות
>
> Our Rabbis taught: ‘And thou seest among the captives’ — when taking
>   her captive; a woman — even married; ‘of beautiful countenance’ — the
>   Torah only provided for human passions: it is better for Israel to eat
>   flesh of [animals] about to die, yet [ritually] slaughtered, than
>   flesh of dying animals which have perished; ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kiddushin.pdf))